# How to not automatically convert byte to ascii in python

Tags: python, hex, arrays, ascii

I´m reading some bytes from UART using Python,

however Python is converting some of my bytes to ascii. This causes problems because therefore I get wrong decimals.

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial("dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=115200,timeout=1.0)

while True:

    port.write(bytearray([0xAA,0x90,0x3B,0x85]))

    answ = port.read(size=8)
    print (answ)
```

the answer I get is:

```
b'\xaa\x10\xb1?\x86ff\x85'
```

However I expect:

```
b'\xaa\x10\xb1\?\x86\f\f\x85'
```

The problems is the ff which has a different value than f f.

Comment: Your expectation is not a proper representation of bytes in Python. I not sure what that should be.

Comment: If 'port.read()' gives you bytes. Could you just print it as a list? There are always issues between byte's and strings.

Answer (score 6):

That display values is just a representation of the data.  Data that is valid ASCII will display the ASCII character, but the bytes are actually:

```
>>> answ = b'\xaa\x10\xb1?\x86ff\x85'
>>> for i in answ: print(hex(i))
...
0xaa
0x10
0xb1
0x3f
0x86
0x66
0x66
0x85
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes and no...
the part '?\x86ff' equals 63134255 as a decimal
however 'x3fx86x66x66' equals 63134102102 as a decimal.

Do you understand my problem?

Comment: @EisBaer, `hex(63134255) == '0x3c35a2f', so that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention the bytes I receive will be converted to decimals. 0xaa, 0x10, 0xb1 and 0x85 is only a start, stop, errorbyte....

Comment: @EisBaer, still, the bytes are displayed are what you claim you actually received and they have no relation to your expectation.  You probably need to show more of your code, with your decimal conversion as well, and document the protocol so it makes sense to us.

Comment: sorry I figued out what my problem is! I was using an online-converter and did not code the whole thing. Now I think I do understand how bytearrays work....

Comment: @EisBaer Saw this old question/answer and realized the data looked like a 32-bit float value since 0x3f866666 converted using IEEE 754 float32 rules is 1.05.

Answer (score 0):

A bytearray is, as the name suggests, an array of bytes. When you receive the data you get the exact bytes that were sent which are then stored in your `answ` variable. However when you print to the screen python assumes an ASCII encoding so anything that is a printable character is *printed* as that character and not as the hex, but they are actually the same as the following code snippet shows:

```
a = b"f"
b = b"\x66"
if a == b:
    print("Same")
else:
    print("different")
```

This prints "Same", which you can see in action here: http://ideone.com/6980Ty

Look up an ascii-table to see how the conversions are made. If you are on linux you type `man ascii` at the terminal to see this.